# Win2008R2: Selecting files inside a browser and his file dialog

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

This happens only in the "file choose" dialog, not for example in windows explorer:

1. Open IE Goto gmail.com
2. login and Compose new email
3. Click on "Attach file"
4. Dialog pops up Try to select multiple files by pressing CTRL

I have two Win2008R2, one is domain controller, the other is not.

On the domain controller I'm not able to select multiple files, on the other I am.
The OS is up to date.

Why? Is there any group policy or similar?

Comment: For the love of Pete, why are you accessing gmail on a domain controller?

Comment: It's only an example where such a file dialog pops up and this strange behavior exists